# QAbstractSocket::UnsupportedSocketOperationError with QSslSocket

Tags: qt, qsslsocket, qt5.9, qabstractsocket

`QAbstractSocket` throws `UnsupportedSocketOperationError` when connecting to a host over `QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted()`,

Environnement: Qt 5.9.3 Ubuntu 16.04 (virtual machine) also Qt 5.9.3 Fedora 26 (native)

```
_socket = new QSslSocket{this};
connect(_socket, static_cast<void(QAbstractSocket::*) QAbstractSocket::SocketError) (&QAbstractSocket::error), this, &EventResource::streamError);

_socket->connectToHostEncrypted(_device->addressUrl().host(), 443, QSslSocket::ReadWrite, QSslSocket::IPv4Protocol);

void EventResource::streamError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
{
    QDebug() << "Event error: " << error; 
    //QAbstractSocket::UnsupportedSocketOperationError
}
```

Can you please help me?
I don't understand the error and why it is happening?

Comment: Your virtual machine does not support it. `UnsupportedSocketOperationError: The requested socket operation is not supported by the local operating system (e.g., lack of IPv6 support).`

Comment: Today i tested it on a Fedora 26 (no virtual machine) and it is also happening.

Comment: Then your IP address is not correct. The code does not contain any error (beside your weird { } when creating the socket on heap)